# How to launch EC2 instance with same IP address as one used by Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to launch an EC2 instance into same private subnet as one attached to a Lambda function so EC2 use the same IP address. I need this because a legacy system whitelisted that IP address so I need EC2 to use this specific IP address. However I cannot SSH into this instance (no public IP available)? I need to solve this to investigate an issue and need to run `traceroute`. Traceroute is not available in Lambda.

Comment: Does "legacy" means you can not even reconfigure/rebuild whitelisting a different address? BTW I think Lambda doesn't guarantee persistency of the IP address of the underlying executioner Amazon Linux instance.

Comment: It would take 4 months so not an option for now. Lambda does guarantee that via elastic IPs and if attached to a private subnet

Comment: Oh Gosh. Let's hope there's some way to migrate the "Lambda elastic address" to EC2 and have it appearing there. If not, hopefully after those 4 months you are able to edit the white listed address/es more easily, that'd make this type of migration easier.